# php preg_match over 100k become false

Tags: php, preg-match

i have a preg_match code like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,5}\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i", $vdoname)){
    echo "vdoname: $vdoname is invalid. Err #1. Exiting ..."; exit();
}
```

If the $vdoname is below 100k value, example: 1000.wmv it return true, however when $vdoname is over 100k like this: 101433.wmv it become false, it suppose to be true. I think that something wrong with the preg_match code, can anyone help me with this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,5}\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i", $vdoname)` {1,5} means you will get from 1 to 5 digits, so when 6 appers your regexp is invalid.

Comment: RegularExpressions are really complicated in the beginning, but as long as you are willing to try it, they will become more and more comfortable. Have a nice day :)

Comment: thanks, why do i get vote down for my question.. i think i asked properly, and not asking non sense question. i wonder why there is so many kind of troll that like to devote people question

Comment: Fixed that for you, don't get demotivated, hard work pays off.